# "A direction I want pursue further"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

From the preface of my thesis:

*I am also grateful to [the institute] for allowing me to conduct my thesis there and for showing me how the latest advancements in technology can be used in humanitarian settings which is a **direction I wish to pursue further**.*

To native speakers, does this sound ok (especially the bold part)? Originally, I wrote

***"a direction I wish to pursue my further career in"***

then I thought that sounds odd and I changed it to

***"a direction I wish to pursue in my further career"***

Now I think what is in the text is the best option. But I still have doubts because "further" can be used as a verb instead of "pursue" so I'm not sure if both should be included. And, since it is the preface, I'd like to make sure it sounds natural.

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't sound right to me. Why are you grateful to the institute? Why do you think *they allowed* you to write your thesis? That is a part of your degree. It isn't like you begged for it? Also, "conduct my thesis" sounds very odd to me. May be "conduct my thesis research/work"?

Comment: thanks! by the "institute" i dont mean my university (then it would be like you say), but a research institute in a different country where I applied to do the thesis. so i am not grateful for allowing me *to write* my thesis but for allowing me to write my thesis *at their institute* (and paying me for doing so). does it now seem reasonable to say i am grateful?

Comment: Yes, now that makes sense ... Thanks for clarifying ...

Comment: What do you mean by "direction"?

Comment: These above comments are mostly discussing the semantics/word choice, but I would like to point out that purely grammatically, it should be '_future_ career' (since 'further' - in the sense you are trying to use it in - is an adverb, not an adjective). Also, in a formal setting like a thesis, I would suggest adhering to the not-ending-sentences-with-a-preposition 'rule' - so your first example, if you choose to go that way, should likely be changed to 'a direction _in which_ I wish to pursue my ---further--- _future_ career'